# please tell me whats wrong in this code

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char *fp = "Alex";

    cout<<fp <<" "<<(void*)fp<<endl;

    *(fp+1) = 'p';

    cout<<fp <<" "<<(void*)fp<<endl;

}
```

Comment: There's nothing inherently 'wrong' with code, it all depends on your expectations. What do you expect it to print?

Comment: Please improve your question title so that it describes something about your question.

Comment: No, you tell US what's wrong in that code. As in, what are you trying to accomplish, and what happens when you run it. Paste the error message if there is one. Then we'll explain to you what you need to correct in order for the code to do what you intend.

Comment: @Alexander Gessler: That's not true.  The OP is attempting to modify readonly memory.

Comment: No question mark, no question.

Comment: @Ed S.: it's only wrong if you intend to run it - or if you expect it to conform to the C++ language specification. I just want to point out that 'please tell me what is wrong' with no further explanation is so imprecise that it renders a question almost totally unusable.

Comment: @Alexander: According to the standard, modifying a string literal is undefined behaviour IIRC.

Comment: @Xeo: Sure it is. That is not the point.

Comment: @Alexander: It's _completely_ the point.

Comment: @Alexander: Contrary to your original statement, there *is* something inherently 'wrong' with C++ code that has undefined behavior.

Comment: Come on people. It is a poorly-asked question, but it's hardly worthy of closure, since there's clearly plenty we can comment on regarding his code.

Comment: @Xeo: seriously? The incorrect punctuation means that "please tell me whats wrong in this code" is "not a real question", but "Please tell me: what's wrong in this code?" would be? Poor speakers of English can just toddle off and get their programming help elsewhere, I suppose.

Comment: @Steve: That was not my intent, but what I meant was that the OP really didn't ask a real question in the sense of SO. He/she should at least tell us something about the code.

Comment: @Steve When you are questioning whether closing a question was the right thing to do, ask yourself. "Can this question be useful to others?" Does its title make it searchable? Does it cover a topic not already in SO. SO isn't here to just answer every single question. But to be a Q&A archive to help people find the information they need. If a question is only beneficial to the OP. It needs to be modified, closed, or deleted. In no way is "What's wrong" help anyone. "Why does my string print incorrectly" would be far more beneficial. However, we're not sure if that's the OP's concern.

Answer (score 6):

You modified a string literal. That's undefined behavior.

Increase the warning level on your compiler, you want a warning/error for the line `char *fp = "Alex";`, because it creates a non-const pointer to immutable data. It's only allowed in C++ for compatibility with C, and it's a misfeature there too.

Comment: Just to clarify, Steve Jessop's and Ed S.'s answers are addressing the same problem. Specifically, "Alex" is a C-style string that you must not modify.

Comment: Sorry about that, Tomalak. Yours, too.

Answer (score 5):

I don't really like answering "questions" like this, but here is an obvious error:

```
*(fp+1) = 'p';
```

`fp` points to readonly memory as you assigned a string literal to it.  Thus, you cannot modify what `fp` points to.  If you want to modify the string declare `fp` as a `char[]` so that it will be allocated on the stack.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to have to assume that you are talking about [the following compiler warning](http://www.ideone.com/3fUXa):

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:5: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
```

Next time please tell us in the question why it is that you think something is "wrong".

As the warning states, converting string constants to `char*`, whilst fairly normal in C, is deprecated in C++.

Do [this](http://www.ideone.com/f6hYO) instead:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char const *fp = "Alex"; // <--- `const` here
    cout<<fp <<" "<<(void*)fp<<endl;
    *(fp+1) = 'p';
    cout<<fp <<" "<<(void*)fp<<endl;
}
```

You will then find that your statement `*(fp+1) = 'p'` does not compile. That is because of the `const`; in fact, the lack of `const` in your original code merely *hid* the fact that **you may not modify the underlying data of that string literal**.

You should copy the characters to a new buffer that your program owns. [You can do this neatly using `std::string`](http://www.ideone.com/F4cbR):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string fp = "Alex";
    cout << fp << " ";
    fp[1] = 'p';
    cout << fp << " ";
}
```

In general, use `std::string` wherever you can. There is rarely a reason to avoid the features of the C++ Standard Library.

Comment: @Xeo: Yes, you can. I hesitate to recommend this to the OP, though.

Comment: fp, being a std::string, contains a copy of "Alex", so changing the second letter to 'p' is fine since it's no longer pointing to the read-only data.

Comment: @camennie: Yes, that's the point of using it.

Comment: I was replying to a comment that was since edited. My comment was slightly more relevant before that, now it's not :P.